# Load balancing docker swarm using Ha Proxy

Tags: docker, tomcat7, haproxy, docker-swarm

I have a Docker Swarm cluster on AWS which I am trying to load balance using HAProxy. My setup which is behind a VPC looks similar to this:

```
haproxy_server 10.10.0.10
docker_swarm_master1 10.10.0.12
docker_swarm_master2 10.10.0.13
docker_swarm_worker3 10.10.0.14
```

My only Tomcat container is currently on master_1  and below is my current HAProxy `config` file:

```
global
log 127.0.0.1    local0
    log 127.0.0.1    local0 notice
    chroot /var/lib/haproxy
stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin
stats timeout 30s
user haproxy
group haproxy
daemon

defaults
log global
mode    http
option  httplog
option  dontlognull
    timeout connect 5000
    timeout client  50000
    timeout server  50000
errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http
maxconn 2000

frontend servers
    bind *:80
    bind *:8443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/certs/ssl.pem
    default_backend hosts



backend hosts
     mode http
     balance roundrobin
     option httpchk OPTIONS /
     option forwardfor
     option http-server-close
     server swarm  10.10.0.12:8443 check inter 5000
```

I am able able to see the index.html page in the webapps directory when I do the following from the HAProxy server:

```
curl -k https://10.10.0.12:8443/docs/index.html
```

However when I try the following `curl` command below, I get a 503 server not available error

```
curl -k https://10.10.0.10:8443/docs/index.html
```

Anyone know what I am doing wrong? I have spent half the day on this to no avail.

EDIT

```
curl -XOPTIONS -vk https://10.10.0.10:8443/docs/index.html

* Trying 10.10.0.10...
* Connected to 10.10.0.10 (10.10.0.10) port 8443 (#0)
* found 173 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* found 692 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* SSL connection using TLS1.2 / ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
*    server certificate verification SKIPPED
*    server certificate status verification SKIPPED
*    common name: *.secreturl.com (does not match '10.10.0.10')
*    server certificate expiration date OK
*    server certificate activation date OK
*    certificate public key: RSA
*    certificate version: #3
*    subject: OU=Domain Control Validated,CN=*.secreturl.com
*    start date: Sat, 27 Jun 2016 16:39:39 GMT
*    expire date: Tue, 11 Jun 2020 18:09:38 GMT
*    issuer: C=US,ST=Arizona,L=Scottsdale,O=GoDaddy.com\, Inc.,OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/,CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
*    compression: NULL
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
> OPTIONS / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 10.10.0.10:8443
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
>
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 503 Service Unavailable
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Connection: close
< Content-Type: text/html
<
<html><body><h1>503 Service Unavailable</h1>
No server is available to handle this request.
</body></html>
* Closing connection 0

curl -XOPTIONS -vk https://10.10.0.12:8443/docs/index.html

* Trying 10.10.0.12...
* Connected to 10.10.0.12 (10.10.0.12) port 8443 (#0)
* found 173 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* found 692 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* SSL connection using TLS1.2 / ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
*    server certificate verification SKIPPED
*    server certificate status verification SKIPPED
*    common name: *.secreturl.com (does not match '10.10.0.10')
*    server certificate expiration date OK
*    server certificate activation date OK
*    certificate public key: RSA
*    certificate version: #3
*    subject: OU=Domain Control Validated,CN=*.secreturl.com
*    start date: Sat, 27 Jun 2016 16:39:39 GMT
*    expire date: Tue, 11 Jun 2020 18:09:38 GMT
*    issuer: C=US,ST=Arizona,L=Scottsdale,O=GoDaddy.com\, Inc.,OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/,CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
*    compression: NULL
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
> OPTIONS / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 10.10.0.12:8443
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Allow: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Sat, 24 Dec 2016 18:39:27 GMT
<
* Connection #0 to host 10.10.0.12 left intact
```

Comment: Does `frontend servers` need `mode http`?

Comment: Unfortunately adding `mode http` to `frontend servers` or even commenting out  the `mode http` in the `backend` didn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you get a `503 Service Not Available`, then your health check fails.

From your configuration, HAProxy will use `OPTIONS http://10.10.0.12:8443/` which will fail: your backend accept HTTPS connections. To fix that, tell HAProxy to use HTTPS:

```
 server swarm  10.10.0.12:8443 check inter 5000 ssl verify none
```

---

Note: you can enable the stat page with

```
listen haproxy_admin
  bind 127.0.0.1:22002
  mode http
  stats enable
  stats uri /
```

That should help you debug further issues.

**Edit:**

The stat page shows `L7STS/404`, that's the http code HAProxy gets. HAProxy currently checks `https://10.10.0.12:8443/` while you test `https://10.10.0.12:8443/docs/index.html`. Perhaps you should use this url in your check:

```
option httpchk OPTIONS /docs/index.html
```

Comment: Thanks David. I tried your recommendation but still getting the `503 Service Not Available` error message. The stats page as expected is showing the backend swarm service down.

Comment: What does the `LastChk` column on the stat page says ? If you try `curl -XOPTIONS -vk https://10.10.0.12:8443/`, do you get a `200 OK` ?

Comment: Hello David- I have edited the initial question to show what i get when i run the curl command you recommended. I tried it using `10.10.0.10` which is the haproxy IP and `10.10.0.12` which is the swarm IP. The latter yielded a `200 ok`. The `LastChk` column in stats shows ` L7STS/404` in 4ms

Comment: `option httpchk OPTIONS /` tells HAProxy to use `/`, not `/docs/index.html`. You maybe should use this url in your check, see my update.

Comment: Still getting the 503 error when i use the `option httpchk OPTIONS /docs/index.html`

Comment: Does the`LastChk` column still says `L7STS/404` ? Do you have any errors in your backend ? Everything *should* work, the goal now is to find what request HAProxy sends to your application and why it doesn't reply `200 OK`. Could you re-test the curl with HTTP 1.0 ? `curl -XOPTIONS -vk --http1.0 https://10.10.0.12:8443/docs/index.html` If your backend uses vhosts or uses the `Host` header, that would be the cause.